# Android : Chips Library for Contact Selection

Tags: android, contacts

Are there any good libraries for implementing the Chips UI on Android? I have been reading the code for the messaging app but it just seems like infinite reading! :-(

Roman Nurik of the Android Development team has suggested to read these :

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/blob/master/src/com/android/mms/ui/RecipientsEditor.java

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/blob/master/src/com/android/mms/ui/ComposeMessageActivity.java

I am trying to create a view that will allow me to select multiple contacts from the contacts DB. Is there a simpler way than just writing my own version of the platform code?

Comment: Hi Daksh, did u implemented this?

Comment: Check out a library I've made, which is based on what Google has made: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/ChipsLibrary